# Mysql multisource replication : on slave map masters dbname to something like mastername-originaldbname

Tags: mysql, replication, architecture

I need to implement a mysql multisource replication using mysql >=5.7.11, there are already a certain number of mysql servers running which will become masters for the single slave which is going to be installed soon. 
The main problem is that each master has same db name and I would like to avoid conflicts in slave and keep each db replica separated. 
Is there a way to configure the slave to, for example, put master name as prefix of its dbname? 
I mean something like this :
master1.db
master2.db

Or do I really need to choose one of the following :
- Change db name on masters
- Install one slave server for each master
?

Thanks in advance 
Best regards 
magowiz

**UPDATE** :
As described in comments, in short :

I also tried something like that, using a solution borrowed by mariadb that I discovered it's not compatible with mysql : mariadb.com/blog/… . I write something like :

```
[mysqld] 
master1.replicate_rewrite_db=db->db1 
master2.replicate_rewrite_db=db->db2
```

with master1 and master2 the two replication channels but it didn't work , I only obtain replication of first instance db to db1 . Is there a way to use replicate_rewrite_db directive on channel/master base ?

The answer I gave to myself it is NO , you can set up multisource replication, you can rename every replicated db on slave specify the mapping but this directive cannot be related to channel, so you need to have unique db names across all masters in order to make multisource replication work.

Currently it seems that mariadb implements this and mysql not.

Comment: I have question about MySQL version, please provide specific version(s)

Comment: Masters are 5.7.11, slave is 5.7.13

Comment: this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587896/does-mysql-replication-master-db-name-has-to-be-the-same-as-the-slave-db-name

Comment: Yes I already read that link before and also the documentation of the flags proposed but I don't know if you can specify also db master name. In short I have 10 masters, on each master there is one db named foo, they have the same structure and table names, with replication without renaming the 10 db became 1 db on slave, maybe conflicting keys and mixing data. My fear is that if I use the flag you proposed is that I can rename foo to bar on slave but I still have 1 db with mixed data.

Comment: I also tried something like that, using a solution borrowed by mariadb that I discovered it's not compatible with mysql : https://mariadb.com/blog/multisource-replication-how-resolve-schema-name-conflicts . I write something like : 
[mysqld]
master1.replicate_rewrite_db=db->db1
master2.replicate_rewrite_db=db->db2  with master1 and master2 the two replication channels but it didn't work , I only obtain replication of first instance db to db1 . Is there a way to use replicate_rewrite_db directive on channel/master base ?

Comment: @magowiz - Please add the details of what you did but that did not work.  Add them to the Question, instead of hiding them in a comment.

Comment: @RickJames : I added what I think is relevant information under an "UPDATE" title on original question, like you asked. Please feel free to ask me further information or give me advices on how to improve it.

Comment: Are the Masters in a "multi-master" relationship?  Are clients writing to both masters?  Is `db` supposed to always be identical on both Masters?  Then it does not make sense to have two different copies of `db` on the Slave.  You seem to be having an issue with this _solution_; let's backup to the original _goal_.

Comment: Hi Rick, you are right I forgot to add some details about the case : the masters are indipendent, no relationship between them, the only things they have in common are the db name and structure. They are in different geographical places. So if I have 10 master db, I need 10 slave db, since each master contains different data. The goal is to have a live copy (replica) of each one on slave server, probably for read-only purposes. Anyway I have already "solved" renaming each master db so instead of app_db, app_db, app_db I have north_app_db, east_app_db and so on....